# Replace while keeping certain "words" in vi/vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi

For example, if I have `$asd['word_123']` and I wanted to replace it with `$this->line('word_123')`, keeping the 'word_123'. How could I do that?

By using this:

```
%s/asd\[\'.*\'\]/this->line('.*')/g
```

I will not be able to keep the wording in between. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using regex, you could do something like `:%s/\$asd\['\([^']*\)'\]/$this->line('\1')/g`

### Step by step:

`%s` - substitute on the whole file

`\$asd\['` - match "$asd['". Notice the `$` and `[` need to be escaped since these have special meaning in regex.

`\([^']*\)` - the `\( \)` can be used to select what's called an "atom" so that you can use it in the replacement. The `[^']` means anything that is **not** a `'`, and `*` means match 0 or more of them.

`'\]` - finishes our match.

`$this->line('\1')` - replaces with what we want, and `\1` replaces with our matched atom from before.

`g` - do this for multiple matches on each line.

### Alternative (macro)

Instead of regex you could also use a macro. For example,

```
qq/\$asd<Enter>ct'$this->line(<Esc>f]r)q
```

then `@q` as many times as you need. You can also `@@` after you've used `@q` once, or you can `80@q` if you want to use it 80 times.

### Alternative (:norm)

In some cases, using `:norm` may be the best option. For example, if you have a short block of code and you're matching a unique character or position. If you know that "$" only appears in "$asd" for a particular block of code you could visually select it and

```
:norm $T$ct'this->line(<C-v><Esc>f]r)<Enter>
```

For a discourse on using :norm more effectively, read `:help :norm` and [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/vimgolf/comments/wmtep/abusing_macros_part_1_normal/).

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks!  But for some reason I always have to do ".,$" instead of "%s" for the whole file.  Is that a quirk with my vim installation?

Comment: Potentially, however be advised that `:.,$` is not the same as `:%`. The former does from the _current_ line to the end while the later does every line. An alternative would be `:0,$`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
:%s/\$asd\[\'\([^\']\+\)\'\]/$this->line('\1')/g
```