# Adding words in front and at the end of line in VIM

Tags: vim, replace, substitution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace while keeping certain “words” in vi/vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624166/replace-while-keeping-certain-words-in-vi-vim)

Let's say I have several lines like

```
            $adv_id;
            $am_name; 
            $campaign_ids;
            $repeat_on;
            $opt_days;
            $opt_time;
            $am_or_pm;
```

Let's say I use visual mode to select all the lines.. how can I add characters at the start and the end of each line so it looks something like

```
        $_REQUEST($adv_id);
        $_REQUEST($am_name; 
        $_REQUEST($campaign_ids);
        $_REQUEST($repeat_on;
        $_REQUEST($opt_days);
        $_REQUEST($opt_time);
        $_REQUEST($am_or_pm);
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1174350/637284)

Comment: You may find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624166/replace-while-keeping-certain-words-in-vi-vim/11624201#11624201) helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12845307/275567), so the explanation there should help you to understand this substitute. With the lines selected as a visual block, use this substitute command:

```
:'<,'>s/\$\(.*\);/$_REQUEST(\1);
```

As before, the `'<,'>` will be auto-filled for you in the command-line if you have a visual selection.

The difference here is that we're using `\(\)` to make a *capturing group*, which will capture part of the regex, and use it again in the replacement, using `\1`, which refers to the *first* capturing group.

Also, since this regex uses `$` literally to position the replacement, it needs to be escaped: `\$`, since it has a special meaning in the regex: *end of line*.

If you'll need to have *multiple* replacements on a single line, you'll need to add the `g` flag, and you may want to remove the semicolon:

```
:'<,'>s/\$\(.*\);/$_REQUEST(\1)/g
```

The reverse regex, e.g. replacing `$_REQUEST($adv_id);` with `$adv_id;`, is pretty similar:

```
:'<,'>s/\$_REQUEST(\(.*\))/\1
```

Here we capture everything between the parens in a `$_REQUEST(...);` in a capturing group, and that capturing group is the entire replacement.

Comment: Why do we use $ in the front since it indicates end of line?

Comment: @CodeCrack we aren't using it to mean _end of line_ here, hence the need to escape it. We want to use it literally, because the matches that you want to change all begin with the `$` character, so we can use that character literally as the beginning of the match.

Comment: Ah ok! Didn't catch that. Thanks

Comment: What if I wanted to reverse it? Remove $_REQUEST($variable); and just leave the $variable from multiple lines?

Comment: @CodeCrack added a command for the reverse

Comment: Thanks man! You solved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

In visual mode, hit `:` and use this in the command line:

```
:'<,'>s/^\(.*\);$/$_REQUEST(\1);/g
```

The `\(` and `\)` capture the matched expression for the line and the `\1` recalls the captured group in the substitution.

Using the `:'<,'>` tells Vim to filter the current selection through the following command (which is `s` in this case).